# Why do we take the trial solution as $vu$ given $u$ is a solution of LDE with variable coefficients.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $y^{(2)}+Py^{(1)}+Q=0$ is a homogeneous linear differential equation where $P,Q$ are functions of $x$ and not necessarily constants.Suppose $u(x)$ is a particular solution,then why we take the trial primitive as $v(x)u(x)$.What is the reason behind choosing such a trial solution?Is there any aspect of analysis or linear algebra hidden behind?
  One more question,is the operator $D=\frac{d}{dx}$ linear on $C^\infty(C^\infty)$ i.e over the field $C^\infty$.

Comment: @joriki I am still looking for an answer.

Comment: I have got 1 answer but it did not satisfy me,one can still answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *ansatz* makes sense because all terms that contain $v$ (as opposed to its derivatives) cancel due to $u$ being a solution:

$$
(vu)^{(2)}+P(vu)^{(1)}+Q=0
\\\iff v^{(2)}u+2v^{(1)}u^{(1)}+vu^{(2)}+Pv^{(1)}u+Pvu^{(1)}+Q=0
\\\iff v^{(2)}u+2v^{(1)}u^{(1)}+Pv^{(1)}u+v\left(u^{(2)}+Pu^{(1)}+Q\right)=0
\\\iff v^{(2)}u+2v^{(1)}u^{(1)}+Pv^{(1)}=0\;.
$$

This is a first-order differential equation for $v^{(1)}$, so we've reduced the problem of solving a second-order differential equation to the problem of solving a first-order differential equation and then integrating $v^{(1)}$ to obtain $v$.

Comment: actually I wanted to know if we can substitute $y=v(x)u(x)$ actually because any substitution is not anways allowed and can lead to misleading results.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar: Then why didn't you ask that? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You can use whatever trial functions you want. If $u$ has zeros, you might not solutions that don't share those zeros, since $vu$ has the same zeros. Other than that, it's unconstrained.